# Firebase network activity

Tags: angularjs, websocket, firebug, firebase, network-traffic

When using Firebase on the client (Chrome/Firefox) with these scripts:

```
    <!-- Firebase -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.15/firebase.js"></script>
    <!-- AngularFire Library -->
    <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.7.1/angularfire.min.js"></script>
```

And this code:

```
.controller('WaitlistController', ['$scope', '$firebase', function($scope, $firebase) {
    var partiesRef = new Firebase('https://wait-and-eat-justin.firebaseio.com/');

    $scope.parties = $firebase(partiesRef);

    $scope.party = {name: '', phone: '', size: ''};

    $scope.saveParty = function() {
        $scope.parties.$add($scope.party);
        $scope.party = {name: '', phone: '', size: ''};
    };
}]);
```

Everything works just fine (ie. Firebase receives updates), BUT I don't see any network traffic in the Chrome Developer tools nor the Firebug debugger for Firefox.  Why can't I see the Firebase network traffic?  I am assuming its using Websockets.

Comment: When I execute this snippet `new Firebase('https://wait-and-eat-justin.firebaseio.com/').once('value', function(s) { console.log(s.val()); })`, I see a few web sockets calls in Chrome's Network tab: `wss://wait-and-eat-justin.firebaseio.com/.ws?v=5` with one frame `{"d":{"t":"r","d":"s-dal5-nss-16.firebaseio.com"},"t":"c"}`. Can you try if it shows up for you with that snippet?

Comment: Also, whyyyyy would you use 1.0.15 and 0.7.1 when the latest are 2.1.0 and 0.9.1 respectively? It hurts my heart.

Comment: I'd like to know as well. AFAK Firebase uses the internet to communicate with my browser. I don't think that it uses the phone line, telex, or pigeons or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase uses Websockets. If you select WS or WebSockets on your Network tab, and refresh the page, you should see something.
In my case it was loading very early in the page, so it's easy to miss.